# Best way to execute external Javascript function from HTML element's onclick event returned from an Ajax call

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

index.php:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="box"></div>
        <div onclick="getContent()">Open Window</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

script.js:

```
function getContent() {
    //ajax call that returns the html from content.php and places it in the box div
}
function sayHello() {
    console.log('Hello');
}
function sayGoodBye() {
    console.log('Good Bye');
}
```

content.php:

```
<div onclick="sayHello()">Say Hello</div>
<div onclick="sayGoodBye()">Say Good Bye</div>
```

What is the correct way to make the functions sayHello() and sayGoodBye() work?
Currently they do nothing.

Comment: Can you show the RENDERED html? it should work if this is what you get from the server.

Comment: @gdoron the rendered html would be the index.php exactly as it is here but then content.php is being injected into the <div id="box"></div> once clicking the Open Window link

Comment: Then I don't know... It should work. Can you make a non working demo at http://jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your element comes from ajax and append to `#box` dynamically, so you need an delegate event handling.

```
$('#box').on('click', '#newElement', function() {

});
```

Syntax for delegate of `.on()` is:

```
$(container).on(eventName, target, handlerFunction);
```

To trigger you need to use

```
$('#box div').eq(0).click(); // sayHello()

$('#box div').eq(1).click(); // sayGoodBy()
```

#### NOTE

I think it should work normally

**[Look here](http://jsfiddle.net/qWpmt/2/)**

#### And its also possible to trigger those click events

**[Check this](http://jsfiddle.net/qWpmt/3/)**

Comment: The click handlers are defined inline.

Comment: How would I then trigger this function elsewhere in my program?

Comment: @thecodeparadox yes but how do I trigger the event elsewhere in my program if the box div is empty? e.g. I want to run console.log('Hello'); from another link somewhere else.

Comment: @Craig I think it should work normally, I've shared a fiddle at the end of answer, check that

Comment: @gdoron It works normally, please check my demo at end of my answer

Comment: The problem is, that according to the code in the question it should work without anything else.

Comment: @thecodeparadox I can see that it works in jsFiddle, but that does really use an external js file.

Comment: @Craig just define those `sayHello()` and so on functions before any external js load and I think it will work and you can trigger also those clicks, check my second demo

Comment: :( never mind I found the problem, had a blank function with the same name about 100 blank lines below *hangs head in shame*

Answer (score 0):

Please keep file index.php, script.js, content.php in the same folder.

**index.php**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="box"></div>
        <div onclick="getContent()">Open Window</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```
function getContent() {
    //ajax call that returns the html from content.php and places it in the box div
    $.ajax({
        url: 'content.php',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#box').html(data);
        }
    });
}

function sayHello() {
    console.log('Hello');
}

function sayGoodBye() {
    console.log('Good Bye');
}
```

**content.php**

```
<?php

$strContent="";
$strContent.="<div onclick='sayHello()'>Say Hello</div>";
$strContent.="<div onclick='sayGoodBye()'>Say Good Bye</div>";

?>
```